# List item permissions and Sharing not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-item, item-level-permissions

**Requirement**

Only the creators of list items should be able to see the list items, till they do not share it with other users. Once the creator shares the list items with other users (View/Edit), now the other user should be able to see these list items in the list.

Process I followed:

1. I stopped the list from inheriting permissions from the site.
2. Added user2 in the group which has read permissions for this list.
   3 In advance settings, I checked these settings:

-> Read items that were created by the user

-> create items and edit items that were created by the user

3. Then I created an item using user1 and shared this item with user2.

**Problem**

Still user2 is not able to see the shared items. User2 does receive an email with the shared item link but when he tries to open it, gets below error:

[image]

Any suggestion where I could be going wrong? Or is it an error from SharePoint side?

Answer (score 1):

Since in advance settings, you checked these settings:

-> Read items that were created by the user

-> create items and edit items that were created by the user

Which means only users with the Cancel Checkout permission can read and edit all items.

[image]

So to make user2 can see items created by user1, at least grant user2 with "Design" permission on the items.

Answer (score 0):

The option for the user to read and edit only items created by themseleves is set on a list. Hence once the created item is shared the other user won't have access to it.
You could use a Sharepoint workflow like set a column and when user shares, trigger the workflow to grant the permissions required for the user through the workflow.